# pygame.error: video system not initialized(pycharm)

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to learn pygame by replicating and examining this: https://www.wikihow.com/Program-a-Game-in-Python-with-Pygame#Adding_a_Player_Object_sub

however when I run either the original version(step 4) as seen above or my code
it brings me a black screen and this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mohamed/Desktop/mopy/pys/first pycharm.py", line 77, in <module>
    game().gameloo()
  File "C:/Users/Mohamed/Desktop/mopy/pys/first pycharm.py", line 60, in gameloo
    self.handle()
  File "C:/Users/Mohamed/Desktop/mopy/pys/first pycharm.py", line 74, in handle
    for event in pygame.event.get():
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

here is my code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

resolution = (400, 350)
white = (250, 250, 250)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (250, 0, 0)
green = (0, 250, 0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(resolution)

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, xPos=resolution[0] / 2, yPos=resolution[1] / 2, xVel=1, yVel=1, rad=15):
        self.x = xPos
        self.y = yPos
        self.dx = xVel
        self.dy = yVel
        self.radius = rad
        self.type = "ball"

    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.circle(surface, black, (int(self.x), int(self.y)), self.radius)

    def update(self):
        self.x += self.dx
        self.y += self.dy
        if (self.x <= 0 or self.x >= resolution[0]):
            self.dx *= -1
        if (self.y <= 0 or self.y >= resolution[1]):
            self.dy *= -1

class player:
    def __init__(self, rad=20):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.radius = rad

    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.circle(surface, red, (self.x, self.y))

ball = Ball()

class game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(resolution)
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.gameobjct = []
        self.gameobjct.append(Ball())
        self.gameobjct.append(Ball(100))

    def handle(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()

    def gameloo(self):
        self.handle()
        for gameobj in self.gameobjct:
            gameobj.update()
        screen.fill(green)
        for gameobj in self.gameobjct:
            gameobj.draw(self.screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        self.clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

game().gameloo()
```

Answer (score 1):

You've initialized the window twice [`pygame.display.set_mode()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode). Remove the global window initialization, but keep and use the window set to the `.screen` attribute of the class `game`.
The method `handle` should only do the event loop, but the method `gameloo` should contain the main loop. Inside the main loop the events have to be handled by `self.handle()`:

<s>`screen = pygame.display.set_mode(resolution)`</s>

```py
class game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(resolution)
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.gameobjct = []
        self.gameobjct.append(Ball())
        self.gameobjct.append(Ball(100))

    def handle(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

    def gameloo(self):
        while True:
            self.handle()
            for gameobj in self.gameobjct:
                gameobj.update()
            self.screen.fill(green)
            for gameobj in self.gameobjct:
                gameobj.draw(self.screen)
            pygame.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick(60)

game().gameloo()
```